# MS SQL Server does not create tables in a specified filegroup

Tags: sql-server, filegroups

I have three filegroups in my database:

[image]

Default is TERTIARY. Now I want to create table on PRIMARY and it shows the following error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'primary'.

```
create table tb1
(
    id int identity primary key nonclustered,
    somecolumn nvarchar(15)
)
on PRIMARY;
```

When I change the default filegroup option to PRIMARY it lets to create tables on PRIMARY. 
Why does it show this error when my syntax is not wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem stems from the fact that **PRIMARY** is a reserved word.  There are several options for the `ON` clause of a `CREATE TABLE` statement and putting square brackets around the word `[PRIMARY]` eliminates confusion about what you are actually asking SQL Server to do.